# document.querySelectorAll(".clase") vs. document.getElementsByClassName("clase")

Tags: javascript, html

Aparte de las diferencias en soporte por parte de navegadores antiguos, ¿qué diferencias existen entre hacer:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".clase")
```

o hacer

```
document.getElementsByClassName("clase")
```

en JavaScript? ¿Es alguno de esos métodos más eficiente? ¿Se debería utilizar alguno sobre el otro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera diferencia entre los dos métodos es el tipo que retornan

```
document.querySelectorAll(".clase")
```

retorna una *lista estática* [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) de elementos

Esto significa que los cambios que se le hagan al DOM luego **NO** se reflejarán en el contenido de la lista.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("clase")
```

retorna una colección *viva* [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) de elementos por lo que cualquier cambio al DOM automáticamente actualizará su contenido. Esto significa que pueden aparecer nuevos elementos o eliminarse de la lista al agregarse o quitar clases.

En cuestión de eficiencia no creo que haya mucha diferencia. Hay una nota para `querySelectorAll` y es que este busca usando un algoritmo *primero en profundidad y en pre-orden* de los nodos del documento.

*DOM transversal* siempre es un proceso costoso, lo que creo que si lo hará más eficiente es **a partir de donde comienzas a buscar** ya que ambos métodos permiten cambiar el inicio de la búsqueda usando

```
// Ambos comenzarán a buscar a partir de element
element.querySelectorAll(".clase");
element.getElementsByClassName("clase");
```

Mi recomendación de uno sobre otro:

- Si quieres seleccionar elementos usando cualquier selector CSS, operar en ellos y luego desechar dicha selección usa `querySelectorAll`
- Para observar conjuntos de elementos usa `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Genial respuesta. Muy conciso y bien explicado :)